How to deploy Docker Container in Google Cloud
I am new to the GCP. I want to move my distributed system, which runs locally using Docker, to the cloud. I have already tried to bring my containers into the cloud, but unfortunately it doesn't work. I have a custom programmed web server that responds to hhtp post and get requests. A bookmaker that can create bets. The bookmaker and the web server communicate with each other via GRPC. As there are several bookmakers, they communicate with each other via MQTT.
This is how I already proceed. I have my code in GitHub and access the repository from the GCP and try to get the containers into GCP. Unfortunately, that doesn't work.
Here my docker-compose.yml file:
services:
  webserver1:
    container_name: webserver1
    image: webserver
    build:
      context: ./webserver
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - '50059:50059'
    environment:
      - HTTPPORT=8080
      - GRPC_PORT=50059
  testservice:
    container_name: testservice
    build:
      context: ./Testing
    depends_on:
      - webserver1
  buchmacher1:
    container_name: buchmacher1
    image: buchmacher
    build:
      context: ./Buchmacher
    ports:
      - '5007:5007/udp'
      - '50051:50051'
    environment:
      - GRPC_PORT=50051
      - CONTAINER_NAME=buchmacher1
      - WEBSERVER_PORT_GRPC=50059
      - WEBSERVER_NAME=webserver1
    depends_on:
      - webserver1
  
  buchmacher2:
    container_name: buchmacher2
    image: buchmacher
    build:
      context: ./Buchmacher
    ports:
      - '5008:5008/udp'
      - '50052:50052'
    environment:
      - GRPC_PORT=50052
      - CONTAINER_NAME=buchmacher2
      - WEBSERVER_PORT_GRPC=50059
      - WEBSERVER_NAME=webserver1
    depends_on:
      - webserver1
  # sitespeed:
  #   container_name: sitespeed
  #   image: sitespeedio/sitespeed.io:33.6.0
  #   build:
  #    context: ./WebTesting
  #   volumes:
  #     - "./WebTesting:/sitespeed.io"
  #   depends_on:
  #    - webserver1
  #    - buchmacher1
  #    - buchmacher2
  #   command: ["http://webserver1:8080/Wetter.html", "-b", "chrome"]
  
  mqtt-broker:
    image: eclipse-mosquitto:2.0.18
    container_name: mqtt-broker
    ports:
      - "1883:1883"
      - "9001:9001"
    volumes:
      - ./mqtt-broker/config:/mosquitto/config
      - ./mqtt-broker/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./mqtt-broker/log:/mosquitto/log

  news-feed:
    container_name: news-feed
    image: newsfeed
    build:
      context: ./NewsFeed
    depends_on:
     - mqtt-broker
  autowetter:
    container_name: autowetter
    image: autowetter
    build:
      context: ./Autowetter
    depends_on:
     - mqtt-broker

As you can see, there are interdependencies

This is a very broad question. The answer below is a good starting point but there are a lot of things involved. Keep in mind that SO isn't a site to ask for guides or tutorials. I'd suggest to first learn kubernetes.

I would start by creating some kubernetes yaml deployment descriptors as well as some service descriptors to have the ports exposed to the other deployments.
You could do this all in 1 yaml file seperated with '---' for each descriptor. However I advice to put each descriptor in it's own file so you can simply deploy/undeploy only the application you are working on.
This is mainly an issue if you have a loadbalancer service which will assign an external IP and you don't want that to change each time you redeploy your application.
There are also other steps you will need to take. For example the application (which I assume is 'webserver' in your case) will need to have an image pushed on a repository available to the GKE environment. If you are already using the google cloud environment you could just setup a google cloud artifact registry.
Edit:
Once you have your descriptors you will need to do perform following steps:

gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTER_NAME --location=SERVER_LOCATION
kubectl apply -f .yaml

